# UITableViewController and UIViewController in Xcode Swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift4

In iOs app , im calling the RootViewController class from the appdelegate which is inherited to UITableViewController ,

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class RootViewController : UITableViewController
{


    // MARK: - View lifecycle
    override func loadView()
    {
        super.loadView()
        self.title = " Sample App"

    }

}
```

if i run this code im getting an empty tableview in ios application , but if i change it to UIViewController which inturn is connected to a storyboard , im getting a black screen .i tried checking on internet but no luck .

Comment: ok, but what is your question?

Comment: i need to display the storyboard that is linked to the viewcontroller , but currently im getting a blackscreen .@Wladek Surala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change it to `UIViewController`, you have no `UIView`-Object like the TableView of an `UITableViewController`. I think you have to add an `UITableView`-Object to your `UIViewController` manually.

Comment: what you want @dinesh? you want to load TableView or UIView? 

as soon as you change class from UITableViewControllers to UIViewController you need to change view as well and connect and vice versa.

Comment: @ Rishi Chaurasia I wanted to load a Storyboard , which is connected to a UIViewController ie) RootViewController . by default salesforce app comes with UITabelViewController , i need to display my storyboard instead of that.